# Linear Algebra Complex Eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Below are the problems from the book.

Find the angle of the rotation and give the scale factor r.
I'm all set with finding the scale factor but I'm having a bit of trouble with finding the angle.

> 1. $\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt(3) & -1\\1 & \sqrt(3)\end{bmatrix}$
>
> To find the angle, I did $\arctan(1/\sqrt(3))$ and got  $\pi/6$
>
> 2. $\begin{bmatrix}-\sqrt(3)/2 & 1/2\\-1/2 & -\sqrt(3)/2\end{bmatrix}$
>
> The angle turned out to be exactly same as number 1,
>   $\arctan(1/\sqrt(3))$ and got $\pi/6$.

But the answer in the book says it's $\frac{-5\pi}{6}$
Is it ok to write the answer as $\frac{\pi}{6}$ or does it have to be **$\frac{-5\pi}{6}$**, if so can you explain why?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the usual convention, a rotation matrix is of the form

$$\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta&\!\!-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}$$

In your case (2) we get $\;\cos\theta ,\sin\theta <0\;$ and thus we are in the third quadrant in the trigonometric circle, that's why the answer is $\;-\frac{5\pi}6\;$, which gives the same result as $\;\;2\pi-\frac{5\pi}6=\frac{7\pi}6\;$

Answer (score 1):

Here you used the identity $\arctan(\tan(x))=x$, which is only valid if $x\in\left]-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right[$.

In your second example, you have $\cos(\theta)=-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, which shows that $x\not\in\left]-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right[$.

But using the fact that $\cos(\theta)=-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and $\sin(\theta)=-\frac{1}{2}$, if you draw the trigonometric circle, you can see that $\theta=-\frac{5\pi}{6}$ is the only angle of $]-\pi,\pi]$ that satisfies these equalities.